# Space between <div> and a script

Tags: html, google-custom-search

I would like to insert a space between the `<div>` border and Google Custom Search box, like this (made with paint):

[image]

but by default it's like this:

[image]

How to?

Comment: Can you show the html and css code?

Comment: `.gsc-control-cse {padding-top: 5px; padding-left: 30px; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's done with CSS using padding-left. i.e.

```
selector {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```